# Firefox v.5 and up - focus text cursor on anything

Tags: firefox

I have noticed that from **version 5 Firefox and up** you can focus typing cursor on anything that is text based ( a, p , h1, h2 etc.. ).

[Screen shot 1](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a0k0ep99)
[Screen shot 2](http://awesomescreenshot.com/087k0erc0)

Any one know how to stop this is CSS? It has no value to the user, and it is ruining my jQuery animations ( e.g. when function is assign to paragraph onclick event).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a default option. Turn off ["Always use the cursor keys to navigate with pages"](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/41/screenshot6ep.png/)

Comment: I don't remember changing any settigns. That solve the problem anyway.

Comment: You can also toggle this with F7. Perhaps you pressed F7 and clicked Yes on the box without reading it (or have the warning box disabled already).